# creating a method in using a (sum series) Write a method to compute the following series

Tags: java, computer-science

```
Then the output looks as followed:

i                         m(i)
1                         0.5
2                         1.1667
... 
19                        16.4023
20                        17.3546




/**
 * Write a description of class fiveonethree here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */

public class homework
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
   {
      double value = 0;
      System.out.println("i" + "\t\t" +  "m(i)");
      System.out.println("-------------------");
      for( int i=0; i < 21; i++)
      {
         System.out.println( i + " \t\t " + value + "\n" );
         value += ((double) i + 1)/(i+2);
      }
   }
}
```

I have my output correct and everything, but my professor wants it in a method. I find methods difficult, so I created it with a simple for loop. The directions are: Write a method to compute the following series: 1/2+2/3.......+i/i+1

Comment: What don't you understand about methods? What do you think `main` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing he/she wants a method that looks like

```
public double theSum(int n) {
    ...
}
```

where `n` is the number of terms (so that the last term is `n/(n+1)`).  Then the `main` method will call `theSum(??)` with some value as the parameter that will be used for `n`.  Of course that will mean you're doing extra computation to print the table, but don't worry about that.  (Maybe you should call it `m` instead of `theSum` since that what they called the function.  I just don't like one-letter function names.)

Comment: ok I have everything  compile but the numbers are not coming out on the output. Did I misplace something? I will update my code

Comment: public class method
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        double result = 0;
        int i;
        System.out.println("i" + "\t\t" +  "m(i)");
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        
    }
    public double theSum(int i, double result)
    {
        for(i=0; i < 21; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(i + "\t\t" + result + "\n");
            result +=(double) (i + 1)/(i+2);   
        }
        return i;
    }
}

Comment: `theSum` won't do anything at all unless you call it from the main method.  And the idea, I think, is that `theSum` doesn't print anything.  You give it an integer, and it computes the sum and returns it.  The main method will call on it, giving it an integer, and then it will use the result and print it.  Understanding how methods (also called procedures, functions, subroutines depending on the language) is so very fundamental, that if you are having trouble understanding how they work, your _first_ priority is to learn that.